# Terraform Github Provider - Destroy results in 404 not found []

Tags: terraform-provider-github

I have built and configured a Github repo using Terraform and the github integration.  Github permissions are course-grained, so I need to give the repo users administrator privs on the repo.  I am also using the "**github_repository_file**" resource to update a file in the repo.

When attempting a terraform destroy, the plan throws the following error:

```
 Error: unexpected status code: 404 Not Found
│ 
│   with module.sciclops.module.gha.github_repository_file.yml_file,
│   on ../terraform-azurerm-sciclops/modules/gha/gha.tf line 27, in resource "github_repository_file" "yml_file":
│   27: resource "github_repository_file" "yml_file" {
```

Tracing the error, I've determined that the user has manually deleted the repo, so of course the repository file no longer exists. I would have expected Terraform to handle tracked (but manually deleted) resources gracefully, and remove the entry from the state file.

Has anyone else run into this issue with the github provider?

I'm seeing something similar documented here: https://github.com/integrations/terraform-provider-github/issues/481